# Allow change in Runnable object

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

When I change an object I have in a runnable AFTER the runnable has been put into a `Thread`, it no longer gets the changes.

**For example:**

Main-class:

```
//Data objects
private GreenhouseBO g;
//Greenhouse-thread
private GreenhouseRunnable greenhouseRunnable;
private Thread greenhouseThread;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Make greenhouse object
        g = new GreenhouseBO("192.168.0.100", 1234);

        //Make runnable
        greenhouseRunnable = new GreenhouseRunnable();
        greenhouseRunnable.addGreenhouse(g);

        //Make thread
        greenhouseThread = new Thread(greenhouseRunnable);
        greenhouseThread.start();

        //Now greenhouseRunnable's run while loop will print GreenhouseBO's address every second.
        //But when I change the GreenhouseBO object, it doesn't go through to the runnable.. It still prints the "old" greenhouse-objects data...
        System.out.println("Setting port....");
        g.setPort(5678);

        /*
        Actual output:
        Address: 192.168.0.100:1234
        Address: 192.168.0.100:1234

        Expected output:
        Address: 192.168.0.100:1234
        Address: 192.168.0.100:5678
        */

}
```

GreenhouseBO.java:

```
public class GreenhouseBO extends Observable {
    private int temp_in;
    private String ip;
    private int port;

    public GreenhouseBO(String ip, int port) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public int getTemp_in() {
        return temp_in;
    }

    public void setTemp_in(int temp_in) {
        this.temp_in = temp_in;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

}
```

GreenhouseRunnable.java:

```
public class GreenhouseRunnable implements Runnable {
    private GreenhouseBO g; //Business-objekt

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Address: " + g.getIp() + ":" + String.valueOf(g.getPort()));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GreenhouseRunnable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addGreenhouse(GreenhouseBO g){
        if(g == null){
            this.g = g;
        }
    }

    public void clearGreenhouse(){
        this.g = null;
    }
}
```

How can I make this work so I can change my `GreenhouseBO` object, and the runnable "recognizes" that the `GreenhouseBO` have change.

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077258/learn-java/observer-and-observable.html

Comment: @almasshaikh sorry, but I can't see how it will solve my problem?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you extending `extends Observable`? If it's not needed, have you tried removing it?

Comment: @munyul I use it somewhere else in my project. Just not included that in my example code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing is that you do never set this `GreenhauseBO` in the `GreenhouseRunnable`

```
public void addGreenhouse(GreenhouseBO g){
    if(g == null){ // g refers to the parameter
        this.g = g;
    }
}
```

should be probably

```
public void addGreenhouse(GreenhouseBO g){
    if(this.g == null){
        this.g = g;
    }
}
```

Second...

In your code you assign the `GreenhouseBO` to a variable `g`, but your code only shows an instance variable `g`. Since you make the assignment in a static context `static void main`, this should not compile. Is there more code that you have not posted.

```
private GreenhouseBO g;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Make greenhouse object
    g = new GreenhouseBO("192.168.0.100", 1234); // where is the static `g` variable
```

or did you mean

```
private static GreenhouseBO g;
```

Comment: @Elias I found one more thing to mention and updated my answer.